# 502 Bad Gateway using Beautiful Soup, Python/Django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Beautiful Soup works in the Python shell using Django. I can also successfully import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` into views.py, but when I call something like `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)`, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. I talked to my host, and they could not find the problem. Any ideas?

Note the xml is `xml = urllib2.urlopen("http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=000000&results=details&index1=isbn&value1=0000").read()`, but it works in the Python shell (within myproject folder), so I wouldn't think that's the problem.

Comment: That error wouldn't have anything to do with BeautifulSoup. It is likely a problem on the server from which you are retrieving your data.

Comment: I already submitted a support ticket, and they said it's a problem on my front.

Comment: Like I said, I can call `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)` in my shell but when I call it from `views.py` I get the 502 bad gateway. If I comment it out, I don't get the 502 bad gateway. `from bs4 import Beautiful Soup` works in both views.py and in the shell though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the interaction between Cython and mod_wsgi described [here](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/branker/2010/07/30/django-lxml-wsgi-and-python-sub-interpreter-magic), and explored in a Beautiful Soup context [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/948577).

Comment: I re-explained the problem to my host, and they told me I had to install an older version of Beautiful Soup and so I did. It works now. FWIW, I removed lxml since I don't use it for any of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and pasting that URL into your browser. I get an access key error; fix that and your problem is solved.

Comment: Um. No. The reason it has an error is because I took out the actual API access key and ISBN key. `000000` and `0000` aren't the actual numbers.

Comment: I recommend you try being a bit more polite when asking for help. Have a nice day.