# Unable to load apache server while loading external modules in a class

Tags: python, django, apache, web-applications, beautifulsoup

This is my django project hierarchy

```
project/
       apache/ django.wsgi
       project/ __init__.py, settings.py, urls.py ..
       pages/
             __init__.py
             widgets.py
             website_views.py
       services/
               __init__.py
               apis/
                    __init__.py
                    fparser.py
                    googleData.py
                    wp.py
                    ...
               wservice.py
       ...
```

So, the `wservice.py` is wrap-up like class which lies over all classes of `apis` module. It even provides some common functionality all classes that it inherit.

`wservice.py`

```
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class WidgetService(FParser):
    def post_content_summary(self, post_number):   
        ....
        content_text = content_soup.get_text()

        ...

    def get_random_image(self, post_number):
        ...
        content_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)

        ...
```

`FParser` class is located at `fparser.py`

The methods in `fparser.py` use the above class in this way.

```
from services.wservice import WidgetService
def method1():
    obj = WidgetService()
    m1 = obj.foo1() # described in FParser class
    m2 = obj.foo2() # described in WidgetService class
```

I am using this WidgetService() in `pages/widgets.py`. So, what I found is, when ever I start using `BeautifulSoup`, the apache server is not loading.. Its not even showing any syntax error.

I don't even see any error in log file.

What might have possibly went wrong??? The interesting part is, I haven't faced this kind of error in development server, heroku (gunicorn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the interaction between Cython and mod_wsgi described [here](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/branker/2010/07/30/django-lxml-wsgi-and-python-sub-interpreter-magic), and explored in a Beautiful Soup context [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/948577). Here's [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235579/502-bad-gateway-using-beautiful-soup-python-django) similar to yours.