# Problems running beautifulsoup4 within Apache/mod_python/Django

Tags: python, django, apache, beautifulsoup, mod-python

I'm was trying to render an HTML-page on the fly using BeautifulSoup version 4 in Django (using Apache2 with mod_python).
However, as soon as I pass any HTML-string to the BeautifulSoup constructor (see code below), the browser just hangs waiting for the webserver. I tried equivalent code in CLI and it works like a charm. So I'm guessing it's something related to BeautifulSoups environment, in this case Django + Apache + mod_python.

```
import bs4
import django.shortcuts as shortcuts

def test(request):
    s = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<b>asdf</b>')
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('test.html', {})
```

I have installed BeautifulSoup using pip, `pip install beautifulsoup4`. I tried to install BeautifulSoup3 using standard Debian packages, `apt-get install python-beautifulsoup`, and then the following equivalent code works fine (both from browser and CLI).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import django.shortcuts as shortcuts

def test(request):
    s = BeautifulSoup('<b>asdf</b>')
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('test.html', {})
```

I have looked in Apaches access and error logs and they show no information what's happening to the request that gets stalled. I have also checked /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages, but no further info.

Here's the Apache configuration I used:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/nandersson/src
    <Directory /home/nandersson/src>
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE app.settings
        PythonOption django.root /home/nandersson/src
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/home/nandersson/src'] + sys.path"
    </Directory>

    <Location "/media/">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>
    <Location "/app/poc/">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure how to debug this further, not sure if it's a bug or not.
Anyone got ideas on how to get to the bottom of this or have run into similar problems?

Comment: show us the apache config you used. and the wsgi.py file contents as well.

Comment: I updated with this, thanks. However I'm using mod_python as mentioned so there's no wsgi.py to show.

Comment: totally unrelated but you should import your packages like this: `from django import shorcuts` since you are using python2.7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm using Apache2 with mod_python. I solved the hang problem by explicitly passing the 'html.parser' to get a soup.

```
s = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<b>asdf</b>', 'html.parser')
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. But I would prefer using 'lxml' for performance, however then the same error occurs. Do you know why this happens?
Is it a bug?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. For better performance, I have changed to use lxml. I encounter no problem at all. What's your code?

Comment: Ah, I realized that mod_python is out of date. mod_wsgi is the module updates are being pushed to. This problem disappeared when I replaced mod_python and works with lxml.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the interaction between Cython and mod_wsgi described [here](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/branker/2010/07/30/django-lxml-wsgi-and-python-sub-interpreter-magic), and explored in a Beautiful Soup context [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/948577). Here are [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235579/502-bad-gateway-using-beautiful-soup-python-django) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398911/unable-to-load-apache-server-while-loading-external-modules-in-a-class/11402871#11402871) similar to yours.

Comment: As said in the description, I'm not using mod_wsgi but mod_python.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

In my cases, 'html.parser' often leads to the HTMLParseError 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/beautifulsoup/x_L9FpDdqkc

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue about a year ago, just tried on a similar setup (django+mod_wsgi+apache2) with a new version of BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 and it seems that the problem has been fixed.